# A real question about USB File transfer with Linux stalling mid-way

Tags: discussion

I don't get this behavioural bit with stack exchange and askunbtu. You look for an answer to a specific problem, and there are multiple responses that say "This question has been asked before", but no links to previous answers like we're stupid for asking it.

Instead of snubbing our problem solving requests, why not provide the PREVIOUS ANSWERS that you say already exist and save us searchers time in finding it. If you know everything and have the keys to the kingdom of knowledge, then why not let us peons know where the real answers exist? Heck I can't even follow up with a simple comment on previous answers unless I've got some huge some huge reliability number.

I'm sure this will be ignored and probably deleted by the first responders at askubuntu. You people are stifling innovation with people looking for solutions to simple problems. We are trying to work too. If our questions are stupid, then prove us wrong with an appropriate response, that has an actual solution, instead of hiding behind invisible curtains.

Comment: *'multiple responses that say "This question has been asked before", but no links to previous answers like we're stupid for asking it'* Can you provide a link to a question where this has happened?

Comment: 50 reputation isn't that much. It's 4 accepted answers, 5 answer upvotes, 10 question upvotes, 25 approved suggested edits, 25 answers you accept, or some combination. 3 accepted answers and one question upvote would get you to 50, for instance.

Answer (score 10):

It seems like you're taking this the wrong way. You're not stupid for asking questions. Nobody knows everything. If someone says your question has been asked before, that's simply saying that you're not the first one to have the problem. If they don't have the link, you do not have to search for the duplicate. Feel free to ignore these comments.

> Instead of snubbing our problem solving requests, why not provide the PREVIOUS ANSWERS that you say already exist and save us searchers time in finding it.

It's easier to close the question as a duplicate. If the question or an answer gets edited, it's *significantly* easier to have it in only one place so it doesn't have to be continuously updated.

It's okay if you ask a duplicate question once in a while. It happens to everyone. Just don't do it on purpose and you'll be fine.

> If you know everything and have the keys to the kingdom of knowledge, then why not let us peons know where the real answers exist?

We don't know everything, but we do try to answer questions. Questions are usually answered if they're on-topic and not duplicates. If you don't ever get a good answer and you've got enough reputation, you can [start a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to attract extra attention.

> Heck I can't even follow up with a simple comment on previous answers unless I've got some huge some huge reliability number.

Yep. You need 50 reputation to comment to prevent spammers. You're clearly not a spammer, so gain some reputation and start commenting. Reputation can be gained from asking questions, answering questions, and suggesting edits. Do all three of those well and you'll start to gain quite a bit of reputation.

> I'm sure this will be ignored and probably deleted by the first responders at askubuntu.

Probably not. This doesn't meet the [rules of deletion](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-questions).

> You people are stifling innovation with people looking for solutions to simple problems. We are trying to work too.

We are building a high quality library of questions and answers. Sometimes that means we have to close or delete off-topic questions to keep the overall quality of the site high.

> If our questions are stupid, then prove us wrong with an appropriate response, that has an actual solution, instead of hiding behind invisible curtains.

Once again, nobody said your question is stupid. If someone wants to answer it, they will answer it. However, there is no way guarantee you will get a responses.

As I mentioned before, we are all working together to build a high-quality Q&A library. Sometimes that means dealing with duplicate or off-topic questions. If you have a good question, please ask it. Hopefully you will get a good answer.

Ask Ubuntu can seem harsh at first, especially if your first question is closed and/or deleted. Please don't get angry. Take this time to read [the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help), and your experience will be a lot more pleasant. Once you get to know the place, it's actually a very productive and interesting experience.